# Get Microseconds from DataTime.Now in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

Need to get the Timestamp value from system time with high resolution (microseconds).
I googled and found that we should use StopWatch. But stopwatch is used for difference between of two different time, is it correct?

Comment: You can't get what isn't there. Any microsecond value you get out of `.Now`  is completely arbitrary. If you want precision, use Stopwatch. It's *NOT* used only for differences, it uses a high performance counter

Comment: Can you construct something from the fact that 1 milli second is 1000 micro seconds? You can get milliseconds from the DateTime

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos, How to calculate Microseconds using Stopwatch ?

long microseconds = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L*1000L));   is it Correct?